# List substraction in python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have two lists of different length.

```
a = [8,9,4,7,5,6,1,4,8]
b = [6,4,7,1,5,8,3,6,4,4]
```

I want a list like this:

```
c= a-b

#output = [2, 5, -3, 6, 0, -2, -2, -2, 4]
```

How can i achieve this?

I tried `operator.sub` with map function. But I am getting an error because of different lengths of list.

```
c = map(operator.sub, a, b)
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: `a-b` till the lengths are equal... what to after the length matching ends? a-a or what?

Comment: The [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will stop at the shortest one.

Comment: I removed the pandas and numpy tags since the question and accepted answer just use lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import sub

a = [8,9,4,7,5,6,1,4,8]
b = [6,4,7,1,5,8,3,6,4,4]

output = list(starmap(sub, zip(a, b)))
```

If you do not want to use a *list comprehension*, this can be done with [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap).

You could also use map, though I think starmap is the better option. With map you could use a nested `zip` to shorten the longer argument.

```
output = map(sub, *zip(*zip(a, b)))
print(list(output))
# [2, 5, -3, 6, 0, -2, -2, -2, 4]
```

Answer (score 7):

You may use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) along with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> a = [8,9,4,7,5,6,1,4,8]
>>> b = [6,4,7,1,5,8,3,6,4,4]

>>> [x - y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[2, 5, -3, 6, 0, -2, -2, -2, 4]
```